# Can De Moivre's Theorem be proved using Euler's Formula?

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

Suppose I want to prove the formula, can Euler's formula be used to prove it? Will it be circular? 
For the supposed proof: 
$$(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n=e^{i\theta.n}=e^{i(n\theta)}=(\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta)$$
So is it circular?

Comment: Why do you think it is a circular argument? No pun intended.  - Mark

Comment: Because the textbooks I have read divide it into some cases and prove them separately, but non used this formula. They either used binomial theorem if I remember correctly or induction. @Dr.MV.

Comment: It's not circular if one begins with Euler's Formula, which can be proven a host of ways (e.g., using the Taylor Series for the exponential, sine, and cosine functions).

Comment: Okay, so should I delete this question?

Comment: I wouldn't delete the question, unless you feel that you have resolution and don't believe that this post adds value to the larger community.  I gave your question a +1

Comment: Okay thanks. (y) @Dr.MV.